# Calender view examples in android

Tags: android, calendar

In android ICS or above calender will not work for Api level 8, is there a good custom calender which is easy to use and it support from api 8 onwards

Comment: Do you want to display a calendar? In that case you could use [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

Comment: Hi Xonya, i tried that caldroid but its slow, after clicking on button it takes 3 seconds to show a dialog. dont no why. can you help

Comment: Yes, it could be slow in old devices (I think due to the support library) but 3 seconds seems a lot. Maybe it does too much work inside the adapter class.

Comment: Yes, is there any alternative libs please. guide me if u know something